# Refresh page from browser returns 404

Tags: .htaccess

I am using Laravel for my application. Sorry in advance if this is a known issue. My system works well until I refresh the browser. It happens only when I refresh from the main page which not from other pages of the site. It return 404

Maybe I missed one important thing. It does not happen on my local but only on my VPS

Following is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Inspecting the network from the browser returns cached until the initiator is 404 where I see a duplication on of the path to my site root 
Instead of "mysite.xx/path/mainfolder" it contains "myste.xx/path/mainfolder/path/mainfolder"

[image: Output from browser inspection]

Comment: Try to find more details about the issue using dev tools in the browser. Use the network tab to track request and responses.

Comment: Thank you @isuruS   In the Network I found it is adding twice the path to the index  file https://base.com/folder1/indexfolder/folder1/indexfolder . I just want https://base.com/folder1/indexfoder

Comment: That looks like a relative path issue. But only when you "refresh"?

Comment: ＠MrWhite, Yes  it happens only when refresh

Comment: Just to say, there's nothing actually "wrong" with the `.htaccess` file you posted. What does the network tab show? Any redirects? Is the response cached??  (_Aside:_ That's not a _normal_ "@" symbol? Consequently no notification was sent.)

Comment: MrWhite, I update the post with the output of the network